# What Operating System services are necessary to support kernel-level threads?

Tags: linux, multithreading, kernel, sunos

I am studying Solaris and Linux and am viewing Kernel Level Threads (KLTs) as the fundamental entity that can be scheduled and dispatched by the OS. I know that a multi-threaded OS must store thread execution context and provide mechanisms to schedule and dispatch KLTs, and that kernel level threads handle interrupts, system calls, and provide an interface to the CPU as a resource at the user-kernel interface. I am not clear on what services are necessary to support KLTs in a multi-threaded OS.

[image]

I cannot determine if there is a core kernel process that is necessary to support all KLTs, or if KLTs run interdependently as the base-level of computing. I would like to understand what minimum set of operations (resource allocation, scheduling) is necessary to support an OS with KLTs.

I have looked at Tanenbaums [Tanenbaum's discussion of threads in his distributed systems book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1543057381), [Understanding the Linux Kernel](https://learning.oreilly.com/library/view/Understanding+the+Linux+Kernel,+3rd+Edition/0596005652/ch01.html), and [MultiThreading the SunOS kernel](https://www.usenix.org/legacy/publications/library/proceedings/sa92/eykholt.pdf) but I cannot find an answer to my question.

I believe that answering the question -- What Operating System services are necessary to support kernel-level threads? -- will help me understand how KLTs are implemented.

Comment: I don't know a direct answer to this question, but I can tell you that it's buried in the POSIX threads implementation in Linux at least, and you can compare and contrast POSIX threads with Green Threads and the now obsolete LinuxThreads implementations for context.